# If $A, B$ and $C$ are all non-zero matrices, and $AB = BC$, does it imply $A = C$?

Tags: matrices

I don't see how $A = C$ but I can't find an example that proves otherwise.

Comment: Hint : do you have heard about matrix reduction ? ! ...

Answer (score 4):

$$A=\begin {pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end {pmatrix},B=\begin {pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end {pmatrix},C=\begin {pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end {pmatrix}$$
In fact, you should be able to use generic matrices for this.  If $B$ is invertible and does not commute with $A$ you can just set $C=B^{-1}AB$ and have an example.  We can let 
$$B=\begin {pmatrix} 1&2\\1&3 \end {pmatrix},B^{-1}=\begin {pmatrix} 3&-2\\-1&1 \end {pmatrix},A=\begin {pmatrix} 1&2\\3&4 \end {pmatrix},C=\begin {pmatrix} -5&-12\\4&10 \end {pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\begin {pmatrix} 1&1\\1&2 \end {pmatrix},B=\begin {pmatrix} 1&0\\1&1 \end {pmatrix},C=\begin {pmatrix} 2&1\\1&1 \end {pmatrix}$$

Comment: I appreciate that you've chosen an example where the matrices are invertible

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is generally not commutative, your proposition is false. When cooking up counter examples, you should look to use matrices with very basic properties. @ross-millikan has provided a good example of this.

It is very useful to consider the Identity matrix, Zero matrix (for other examples) and then matrices consisting of a reordering of the columns of the identity matrix.

Ross' examples can be written as

$$A=I_{2\text{x}2}, \quad B = C = e_1 e_1^T$$

where $e_i$ represents the $i$th column of the Identity matrix.